# GO lang exception handling

Tags: go

I am new to go lang. How to achieve subtype inheritance in GO and handle exceptions in it? I am trying something to this but somehow I am not able to get it to work.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.rmi.*;

class class1
{
    public void m1() throws RemoteException
    {
        System.out.println("m1 in class1");
    }
}

class class2 extends class1
{
    public void m1() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("m1 in class2");
    }
}

class ExceptionTest2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        class1 obj = new class1();

        try{
            obj.m1();
        }
        catch(RemoteException e){
            System.out.println("ioexception");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for commenting. Updated the question and my actual question was this.

Comment: @user2864740 question updated. Please do let me know if I can do anything to improve my question.

Comment: So, exception handling *or* how golang handles subtype relationships?

Comment: Go isn't Java, and it has different language features. Perhaps ask a question that describes what effect you're trying to achieve and you'll get a helpful answer about how to do that in Go.

Comment: Go manages errors in a different way than Java. As functions can return multiple values, the idiomatic way is to return an error variable together with the result. There is a panic() and recover(), similar to exceptions, but their use is more limited and usually applies to unrecoverable or exceptional errors. Take a look at http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors for error management.

Comment: @user2864740 question updated :)

Answer (score 7):

As people already has pointed out, Go is very different from Java.
That means you will not have something "very much similar" to the Java code.

**Embedding instead of inheritance**

Go does not have *inheritance* as you might be familiar with it. The closest you might find is called [embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

And while an embedded method might be shadowed by a method of the parent and act as a sort of override, this is not a common way to solve your programming tasks in Go.

**Errors instead of Exceptions**

Panics are not to be used as exceptions. If you want to write Go code, you return errors to inform the calling function/method that something went wrong.

**What your code might look like in Go:**

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    RemoteError = errors.New("A remote error occured")
    IOError     = errors.New("An IO error occured")
)

type Struct1 struct{}

func (s *Struct1) m1() error {
    fmt.Println("m1 in Struct1")
    return nil // or RemoteError
}

type Struct2 struct {
    Struct1
}

func (s *Struct2) m1() error {
    fmt.Println("m1 in Struct2")
    return nil // or IOError 
}

func main() {
    s1 := &Struct1{}

    err := s1.m1()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
m1 in Struct1
```

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/VrhvtQDXCx